# Audio is pitched down by 40Hz

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, steam

i have a weird problem. Whenever I'm lounching Age of Empires 2 Definitiv Edition out of Steam (via Steam Play / Proton) the audio output of my Computer pitched down by 40 Hz (I can tell it's 40, because I checked with a Tuner and a 500Hz Sound). This Problem occurs everytime I lounch the game and can just be fixed by forcing ALSA to reload.

Is there a nicer Way to Fix that? I dont wanne hear my Music pitched 40Hz down when playing AOE2 and reloading ALSA ends up in having normal Sound for my Music but no Sound in AOE2.

I have Ubuntu 20.04.

Edit:
This Problem occurs on other times, but launching AOE2 doest it every time.

Edit:
My Setup is the following:

- MSI B450m PRO-VHD MAX
- RYZEN 5 2600
- Radeon RX580 (Due to Problems with the Graphics I'm using amdgpu.dc=0 in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT)
- As an Audio Interface: focusrite scarlette 2i4
- Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Linux version 5.4.0-54-generic

Hope I got all the Information needed.

Comment: *"This Problem occurs on other times, but launching AOE2 doest it every time."* -- your recent edit changes a lot. This means that this specific application can not be the cause of the problem. Please edit your question and include all of your hardware details as it pertains to sound. What's the sound card/adapter in use?  Are you using speakers or headphones? If speakers, are they built in, like laptop speakers?  If not, how are they connected?

Comment: @Nmath I've added everything I thought might be helpfull. If i forgot sth plese let me know!

Comment: For diagnostic purposes, please eliminate all variables to rule out that this is not a problem with your hardware itself.  In particular, the USB DAC should be disconnected to determine if this hardware is the true cause.  This knowledge could help you determine future steps.